# How do I post my CSV data to JSON placeholder? This code is telling that the POST request fails

Tags: csv, http-post

import csv
import requests

## Open the CSV file

with open('/home/1da70697-89c0-49f8-a226-00e407badde0/Shreyas Natesan - Bodybuilding & Strength Prep II - Weight Training Log 2023.csv','r') as file:
# Create a CSV reader object
reader = csv.reader(file)

```
# Skip the header row if it exists
next(reader)

# Read the CSV data row by row
for row in reader:
    # Extract the values from the row
    value1 = row[0]
    value2 = row[1]
    
    data = {'value1': value1,'value2': value2}
    
    
    # Do something with the values
    print(value1, value2)
    
    
    # Make the POST request to the dummy site
    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'  # Replace with the dummy site's URL
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    
    # Process the response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('POST request successful')
    else:
        print('POST request failed')
```

I ran the above code to try and post CSV information to JSON Placeholder. However, I keep getting notices that the POST request failed. My goal is to practice with API POST requests and have my CSV information actually successfully POST to a site. Not sure if JSON Placeholder is the best one to use, but I just want to create code that successfully POSTs and see how that manifests